# ArcGIS/Python: How to sum rows based on a common ID

Tags: python, numpy, arcgis, arcpy

So, I would like a way to sum values in a table based on  a common identifier (in the table below, the field 'IWUP').   My table looks something like this:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|IWUP                |Site                |Date                |PPG
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|1985001             |1234                |01/01/2012          | .03                |
|1985001             |1235                |01/01/2012          | .23                |
|1985001             |1236                |01/01/2012          | .35                |
|1985001             |1234                |01/02/2012          | .03                |
|1985001             |1235                |01/02/2012          | .03                |
|1985001             |1236                |01/02/2012          | .03                |
|1985001             |1234                |01/03/2012          | .03                |
|1985001             |1235                |01/03/2012          | .03                |
|1985001             |1236                |01/03/2012          | .03                |
```

It's temporary table generated by some arcpy code this this:

```
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(PUMPAGE_PPG_DATA, PPG_DATA_View, "IWUP =1985001", "", "IWUP; SITE; DATE; PPG")
```

I'd like to sum the PPG data for each Site  and Month and produce something like this:

```
 +--------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+
 |IWUP                |Date                |PPG
 +--------------------+--------------------+----------------------------+
 |1985001             |01/02/2012          |SUM(Sites 1234, 1235, 1236) |          
 |1985001             |01/03/2012          |SUM(Sites 1234, 1235, 1236) |   
 |1985001             |01/04/2012          |SUM(Sites 1234, 1235, 1236) |
```

which I can then plot

```
x = []
y = []
fig = plt.figure()
table = QUERY
fields = ["Date", "PPG"]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields) as rows:
for row in rows:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])


plt.plot(x,y, marker='o', linestyle='-', color='b')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Spatial Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/) with PPG as statistics_field and IWUP and Date as case_fields: `arcpy.Statistics_analysis(in_table, out_table, [["PPG", "SUM"]], ["IWUP", "Date"])`